# iOS 11 - Status bar is hidden

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar, ios11

I have two `UIViewController` in my app: main, and player.

In main, the status bar shows. Then main presents player, and in player the status bar is hidden, using `modalPresentationStyle` of `Full Screen`. When I dismiss player, main is shown and the status bar returns.

After upgrading my app to iOS 11, when dismissing player, the status bar does not return.

`View controller-based status bar appearance` is set to NO in my info.plist file.

Comment: Are you using any code? In any app where I hide the status bar at all, I override `prefersStatusBarHidden` in **all** my VCs.

Comment: No code. Notice the last part of the question about the info.plist. If it's NO, the prefersStatusBarHidden isn't called

Comment: Why not try refactoring then? Remove the info.plist key, add in the overrides. Unless if someone else has an iOS 11 answer - hopefully they will - at least it's an option....

Comment: Thanks. I'm hoping this is a bug in the iOS beta and that Apple fixes it without me having to change my code, because there's probably lots of people that will encounter this problem soon.

Comment: I've never filed a RADR (or searched to see if someone has). Maybe you may need to do that. Either way, good luck.